# Can I call a web service using mtom in a .Net Dll from a .Net Core Web Api project?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, soap, .net-core

I know message encoding with mtom from 'BasicHttpBinding' isn't possible in .Net Core.
And I need to call a web service, using it, to send documents to a client. Can I put the web service call into .Net Dll and then call it from my .Net Core app API?

I read that I can, if the call is to a .Net Standard Dll, but not a .Net Framework Dll? Which would this be and is it possible?

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport)
{ 
    // MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom, not supported in .Net Core
    TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed
};

EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(url);
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, endpoint);
var webService = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

I'm a little confused here as to what I can and can't do.

Comment: This can not be achieved in `.Net Core`/`.Net standard` project. It boils down the fact that MTOM encoder has not been implemented in the .Net standard project yet.
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1810

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question the DLL needs to be .NET Standard, again the MTOM is not supported.

You may use the following [.NET Core MTOM Encoder](https://github.com/lennykean/WcfCoreMtomEncoder) by Lenny Kean.

Comment: Hi Islam. I saw this library, but not sure how to use it? Does it replace 'BasicHttpBinding', 'ChannelFactory' and 'CreateChannel'?